# Static site generator that works like GitHub with blog features?

Tags: markdown, static-site-generator

I'm looking for a static site generator that works like GitHub and has basic blogging features. What I mean by 'works like GitHub' is mostly how Markdown gets rendered and relative links between Markdown files work.
https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files

I do **not** want to use Jekyll. I don't like its philosophy of every post filename must start with a date. Why not pull the date from the file metadata or front matter?

Middleman is better since it doesn't have that requirement but out of the box it doesn't rewrite `.md` relative links to `.html` like GitHub does.

Any recommendations?

Comment: What are "basic blogging features"?

Comment: @unor A page that shows a reverse chronological list of articles and rss.

Comment: Hexo (http://hexo.io)?

Answer (score 2):

You can look on [DocPad](http://docpad.org).

It offers [many possibilities](http://docpad.org/docs/intro/), has nice [documentation](http://docpad.org/docs/) and is based on [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)

It supports many markup [plugins](http://docpad.org/docs/plugins/) (markdown, textile, ...). With DocPad you can create complex static blog with advanced features (like non-static functionalities, database querying,

importing pages from external:

- database (MongoDB, MySQL, ...)
- services (Tumblr, Dropbox, GitHub, etc.)

Import data from external services (Atom, XML, JSON, etc.)

You can use **DocPad with GitHub**. You can write into repository to house your wiki content, have DocPad render it, and automatically update on changes. [Here](https://gist.github.com/balupton/5519403) is more info.

What do you mean by "basic blogging features"? In my opinion they can be following:

- easy writing new posts (for example in markdown syntax)
- possibility for adding comments to your blog posts - it can be done with [external service](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-services) like Disqus.
- adding tags to posts, filtering posts by tags

If you are familiar with programming (javascript, Node.js) DocPad [can be](http://erajasekar.com/posts/blogging-platform-hackers-octopress-docpad-poole/) one of the best choice.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Does DocPad meet the requirements? OP e.g. mentions rewriting `.md` relative links to `.html`, integration with Github, basic blogging features. As you're new here, you might wish to take a look at our [answer quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) (no pun intended, please count it as friendly/helpful hint). Then please [edit] your answer to improve it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Nikola](https://getnikola.com/) is a static web site generator written in [python](http://python.org) with the following features:

- Incremental Builds for speed
- Out of the box, supports Markdown, reStructuredText *(default)*, IPython (Jupyter) Notebooks and HTML.
- blogs (with comments, tags, categories, archives, RSS/Atom feeds),
- multilingual support,
- easy image galleries,
- and code listings
- Themes (Mako or jinja2)
- Plugins in python
- Stores things like the blog post date as metadata either inside the file or in a separate file.
- Free, gratis & open source, MIT licence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is quite what you mean, but one option might be [Kirby](http://getkirby.com) is a file-based CMS that doesn't require a SQL database or the like. Content is written in Markdown and the whole thing is highly configurable. I use it for [my own website](http://ciaranokelly.org) because I wanted something that was simpler than WordPress etc.